# Any set with more elements than the dimension of vector space is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n$ such that $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is its basis. Take $A\equiv\{a_1,\cdots,a_p\}\subset V$ with $p>n$.

How do can I show that $A$ is linearly dependent **without having to do all those summations**. Is there an easier more direct proof than that?

Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Well, how do you define the dimension of a vector space?

Comment: **Steinitz Lemma** If $B$ is a spanning set (in particular, a basis) of a vector space $V$ and $A$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, then $|A|\le |B|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If $A$ is linearly independent, then $\dim(\text{span}(A)) = p$, but $\text{span}(A) \subseteq V$. Can you finish the argument?

Comment: $A$ is a basis for $span(A)\subset V\implies dim(V)=n\geq dim(span(A))=p>n$

Answer (score 5):

There are a constructive and a non constructive proof. The constructive proof is known as “Steinitz Lemma”:

> *If $B$ is a finite spanning set (in particular, a basis) of a finitely generated vector space $V$ and $A$ is a (finite) linearly independent subset of $V$, then $|A|\le|B|$.*

This is proved by showing that there exists a subset $C$ of $B$ with $|C|=|A|$ such that $(B\setminus C)\cup A$ is a spanning set of $V$.

The non constructive proof is maybe easier. Since $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, we can write
$$
a_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_{ij}v_j \qquad(i=1,\dots,p)
$$
If $\alpha_1a_1+\dots+\alpha_pa_p=0$, then
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_ia_i=
\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_i\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_{ij}v_j\biggr)=
\sum_{j=1}^n\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_i\gamma_{ij}\biggr)v_j
$$
so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_i\gamma_{ij}=0 \qquad(j=1,\dots,n)
$$
This is a homogeneous linear system in the unknowns $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_p$ and, if $p>n$, it has infinitely many solutions. Therefore $\{a_1,\dots,a_p\}$ is not linearly independent.

There are other proofs, that however depend on knowing more about dimension of (finitely generated) vector spaces.

First fact:

> *Any (finite) linearly independent set in a vector space $V$ can be extended to a basis.*

Second fact:

> *Any two bases of a vector space have the same number of elements.*

Putting together these two facts, you get that a linearly independent set cannot have more elements than a basis.